# Cartesian equation of plane containing point P(2,3,1) and at equal distance to three points A, B and C

Tags: systems-of-equations, plane-geometry

I'm asked to determine the Cartesian equation for a plane through a point $(2, 3, 1)$ and that is at equal distance to three different points $A(1, 3, 5)$, $B(1, 1, 1)$, $C(3, 1, 3)$. I have the formula for the distance between a point and a plane:

$$ d(\vec{p}, V) = \frac{\mid d - ax_0 - by_0 - cz_0\mid}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}$$.

I have also introduced a new variable, $\lambda$, to represent the distance between the plane and the point. Thus I get the system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} \lambda = d(\vec{p_a}, V) = \frac{\mid d -a - 3b - 5c\mid}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}\\ 
\lambda = d(\vec{p_b}, V) = \frac{\mid d -a - b - c\mid}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}\\ 
\lambda = d(\vec{p_c}, V) = \frac{\mid d -3a - b - 3c\mid}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}}\\ 
\end{cases}$$

I have no idea if this is the right start or not, but this is what I went with. But now I'm stuck and I have no idea on how to continue.

Comment: Equation of plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ can be written as $Ax+By+C+1=0$ by dividing by $d$.

Comment: I did that now but I'm still quite stuck.

Comment: A plane equally distant to all three points would be parallel to the plane formed by the 3 points. I don't know if there is a unique equidistant plane off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the equation of the plane be $(x-2)+p(y-3)+q(z-1)=0$ that contains the point $(2,3,1)$. Then, use the point-plane distance formula to establish

$$\frac{|-1+4q|}d = \frac{|-1-2p|}d = \frac{|-1-2p+2q|}d $$

with $d=\sqrt{1+p^2+q^2}$. Solve for $p$ and $q$ to obtain the planes below

\begin{align}
& x=2\\
& x+ 2y -z= 7\\
& x -3y-z= -8\\
& 3x+y+2z=11
\end{align}

Comment: That solves it, thanks!

Comment: @MatthiasK. - no problem

Comment: Interesting, I can see one and thought there might be 2 planes. Anyone have any intuition for 4 planes?

Comment: OK, got it. One plane (your second) is parallel to the plane formed by the 3 points. The other 3 planes are "parallel" to the lines between any two of the 3 points (so that it is equidistant from those two and positioned to be equidistant from the third point)

Comment: @Paul - right. Or, 3 points are on same side of the plane and other 3 planes which are sandwiched between  one and two points